# what is the difference between pooled output and sequence output in bert layer?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, neural-network, text-classification, bert-language-model

everyone! I was reading about Bert and wanted to do **text classification** with its word embeddings. I came across this line of code:

```
pooled_output, sequence_output = self.bert_layer([input_word_ids, input_mask, segment_ids])
```

and then:

```
clf_output = sequence_output[:, 0, :]
out = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(clf_output)
```

But I can't understand the use of pooled output. **Doesn't sequence output contain all the information including the word embedding of ['CLS']?** If so, why do we have pooled output?

*Thanks in advance!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have given a sequence, "You are on StackOverflow". The sequence_output will give 768 embeddings of these four words. But, the pooled output will just give you one embedding of 768, it will pool the embeddings of these four words.

Comment: Thanks  for your response! But how do you identify which to use?

Comment: In general people use 'pooled output' of the sentence and use it for text classification (or for any other specific task).

Answer (score 6):

**Sequence output** is the sequence of hidden-states (embeddings) at the output of the last layer of the BERT model. It includes the embedding of the [CLS] token. Hence, for the sentence "You are on Stackoverflow", it gives 5 embeddings: one embedding for each of the four words (assuming the word "Stackoverflow" was tokenized into a single token) along with the embedding of the [CLS] token.
**Pooled output** is the embedding of the [CLS] token (from *Sequence output*), further processed by a Linear layer and a Tanh activation function. The Linear layer weights are trained from the next sentence prediction (classification) objective during pretraining. For further details, please refer to the BERT original paper.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a [SEP] token as well at the last of the sentence?

Answer (score 0):

As a number of other answers have pointed out, `sequence_output` is token-level with 2 dimensions - the first dimension corresponds to the number of tokens in the input text.

`pooled_output` is one-dimensional and seems to be some sort of a higher-order context embedding for the input text.

I initially felt they should contain practically the same information (or that `sequence_output` should contain more given the additional `n_token` dimension), but right now I'm training a semantic similarity model based on Bert and am seeing definitively better results using both `sequence_output` and `pooled_output` in the model, compared to using just `sequence_output`.